# Javascript: variable as array key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I im building and array where my array key is from a variable like this:

```
var art = $('#article_id').val();
var stk =  $('#stk').val();
elements ={ art : stk };
alert(elements[art]);
```

but i end up with this output `art=>50` instead of `5123=>50`

Comment: Could you please change the title as this question has nothing to do with arrays but with objects. Thx

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### ECMAScript 2015 (aka ES6 Harmony)

ES 2015 provides support for this through a feature called [computed property names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) (although the relevant [section of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-12.2.6) is called "Object Initializer").

Simply put, surround the variable (in general, any expression) with square brackets to evaluate it and use the result as a property name. In your example that would be

```
elements = { [art]: stk };
```

### Original answer (targeting ES5)

You cannot create object literals like that. You need to write

```
elements = {};
elements[art] = stk;
```

The reason why `elements = { art: stk }` does not work is because it is equivalent to `elements = { "art": stk }` (with quotes). The two versions are equivalent in JavaScript as long as `art` is a legal identifier, and the second version makes it clear what's going on.

Comment: Update: ECMAScript 2015 added support for _Computed property names_.  The answer can now be written as `elements = { [art]: stk };`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: @searlea: Thank you for the heads up! I updated the answer to include this information.

Answer (score 13):

Use below to add dynamic key to an object.

```
elements = {};
elements[art] = stk;
```