# Dynamic keys in Javascript associative array declaration one-liner

Tags: javascript

I would expect the following three associative arrays to be identical:

```
arr1 = { "dynamic":"foo", "bar":"baz" };

key = "dynamic";    
arr2 = { key:"foo", "bar":"baz" };

arr3 = {};
arr3[key] = "foo";
arr3["bar"] = "baz";
```

In the above examples, `arr1` and `arr3` are the same, but `arr2` is different.

Is it possible to use dynamic keys in the declaration of a javascript associative array?

Comment: No you cannot use variables as keys in an object literal declaration.

Comment: [N](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6500573/1048572)[o](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4071499/1048572)

Comment: duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key) (and many others)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is *now* possible to use dynamic keys in the declaration of a javascript object, in any browser/platform that supports ES6 literal shorthands:

```
key = "dynamic";    
arr2 = {
    [key]: "foo",  // "dynamic": "foo"
    "bar": "baz"
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Only the `[]` syntax works for dynamic keys. You cannot use them in a literal. So your answer is no, it's not possible.

But you can use a literal to create all the static keys and then add the dynamic ones using the `[]` syntax. That's usually prettier than using the `.` or `[]` notation for *all* elements.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution for this.

Do as following:

```
var field='name';

var ourVar={};

ourVar[field] = 'Somethig';
```

Source: [Javascript: variable as array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244483/javascript-variable-as-array-key)

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a one liner, try this:

```
var key = 'dynamic', obj = (function(o) { o[key]='foo'; return o;})({bar: 'baz'});
```

This will make `obj` equal to `{bar: "baz", dynamic: "foo"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalObj = {};//some data here


function addKeyValuePair(originalObj,key,value){
    originalObj = {...originalObj,[key]:value}
};
```