# ng-repeat over array of objects vs. object containing objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In almost all the examples of ng-repeat I've seen, the data is structured like so:

```
$scope.dataCollected = [{name: bob, data: '10-12-12'}, {name:joe, data: '09-13-13'}];
```

However, the only way I can get ng-repeat to work is if I structure the data like this:

```
$scope.dataCollected = {bob: {name: bob, data: '10-12-12'}, joe: {name:joe, data: '09-13-13'}};
```

Structuring it as an array causes the ng-repeat to do absolutely nothing. It doesn't even give an error. Structuring it as an object containing objects works, but I'd like to use an array because I understand it's the only way to use a filter on ng-repeat.

I'm calling the ng-repeat like this:

```
<div class="list-row" ng-repeat="data in dataCollected">
  <h3 class="name"> {{data.name}} </h3>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your console.. You might have got a syntax error there in your object. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5XUdqwds25MLEt3n6sxo?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm, it's not a syntax error. Both are readable by the console.

Comment: So why don't you use it as an array?

Comment: I'd like to. The array is the version that doesn't work.

Comment: @maskedjellybean that is because i fixed in my plnkr. check the plnkr both works. i.e `{name: bob,` will throw error unless you have a variable named `bob`. if you think array syntax does not work please show us a demo showcasing the issue.

Comment: @Shomz Hope you read my reply for your comment on your deleted answer. :)

Comment: @PSL Yeah, wanted to undelete my answer to write it - sorry, I totally skipped the line where OP is actually showing the array, so I thought he wanted a quick way to filter it.

Comment: @Shomz to be frank. i really have no idea what issue OP has... I even placed a plnk to show it works except for the syntax error. I have voted to close the question

Comment: @PSL You fixed it, I think that's all there was to it, we should close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, thank you for the help. The issue was that in an attempt to make my data easier to read, I had assigned names to the keys of the array using bracket notation as seen in the answer here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/12244483/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244483/)… ng-repeat does not like that at all. It seems the default keys are necessary.