# React native: pass string as function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-router-flux

Actions allows me to load a page from a button. So I would have e.g. 'page1' as a key (which is a function), that i could apply to Actions.page1 and it would navigate to that page. However, here I am only getting the string of this.props.lec, that holds the same characters as the key/funcion that I want. Thus when building get the error message of: 'category is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeFlux.Actions.a({id: this.props.id, title: this.props.title})'. So I believe it will not work because its a string and not a function. So how would i make it as a function?

```
  var a = this.props.lec;
  _onPress() {
    Actions.a({id: this.props.id, title: this.props.title});
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: variable as array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244483/javascript-variable-as-array-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ben said, you will need to use square brackets. However you need to pass arguments as well.

The correct way to go is:

```
const { id, lec, title } = this.props; /* added for simplicity */
Actions[lec].call(undefined, { id, title });
```

Comment: just says cant find variable lec

Comment: ah got it to work by - Actions[this.props.lec].call({ id: this.props.id, title: this.props.title });

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets, like you would with an array.

```
var obj = {
    something: 'ok'
}
var key = 'something';
console.log( obj[ key ] ) ==> 'ok'
```